# Best way to displaying an image in my app from a server?

Tags: android, image, api

Which approach is better to send the image url to the app to display it, or to send the content of the image file to the app (if that supported)?

Comment: there is good libraries like Glide and Picasso that can download images with url from any where to your app and mange memory and cache and some other stuff for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to send only the URL and let some Loading library handle the download and caching for you.

I suggest you to use Glide.

```
 @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

  GlideApp.with(this).load("YOUR_URL_HERE").into(imageView);
}
```

*This code is from Glide GitHub page
https://github.com/bumptech/glide